# Boost.PropertyTree doesn't release memory in destructor

Tags: c++, xml, memory, boost, boost-propertytree

I test the following code

```cpp
#include <boost/property_tree/xml_parser.hpp>

namespace pt = boost::property_tree;

int main()
{
  { //1
    pt::ptree xml;
    pt::read_xml("very_big_xml.xml", xml);
    // xml.clear(); //destructor should do the job
  }
  { //2
    pt::ptree xml;
    pt::read_xml("very_big_xml.xml", xml);
  }
}
```

After first part, my application ocuppies huge memory amount (~6GB) and it crashes on second part because of lack of memory. Should I manually release property tree? Documentation says the destructor should clean up.

NOTE: uncommenting `xml.clear();` doesn't help.

Comment: Have you tried the `std::vector<type>().swap(other)` trick? I would try swapping `xml` with empty temporary just to see what happens.

Comment: @BigTemp I've tried. But this is literally the same as calling destructor.

Comment: What version, compiler, OS, compile flags?

Comment: @rustyx boost 1.65, g++ 7.5.0 on Linux, no additional flags.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that you are trying use [DOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model) for very large xml.

DOM is vary handy and easy to understand, but it fails for large xml-s.

Proper way to solve this problem is to use [SAX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_API_for_XML) which is event driven.
Using this approach you can process large xml even in 32 bit application without consuming large chunks of memory.

Now boost property tree is clearly DOM style and it fails not because ptree is broken, but this is shortcoming of DOM approach.

Most probably you built your application for 32 bit platform, which makes application to have 3GB memory limit.

Comment: You are right - SAX is better for handling very large xmls. But this is not the answer to the question, strictly speaking.

Answer (score 0):

Works fine for me, `boost::property_tree` destructor is releasing memory as expected (Boost 1.73).

[image: boost::property_tree memory usage]

Try running under `gdb` and getting a backtrace (`bt`) when the app crashes.

Also try running under `valgrind` with a smaller file to see if it reports any leaks.